# flow of vector field maps $J_0\times U_0$ into $U$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold ,$X$ is a smooth vector field on it, assume $\theta$ is the flow associated with $X$.Now prove given a point $p\in M$ ,and chart $(U,\varphi)$ around it. we can always find an open interval $J_0$ containing 0,and open subset $U_0\subset U$ containing $p$ such that $\theta$ maps $J_0\times U_0$ into $U$

My attempt: it's sufficient to prove that $\varphi (\theta(J_0\times U_0)) \subset \varphi(U)$ since $\varphi$ is diffeomorphism. Now to prove this intutively since $\theta(0,p) = p$ because $\theta$ is smooth,when $J_0$ is small it can't go too far from central $p$,But I don't know how to prove it regouriously?

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorems on existence, uniqueness, smoothness, and smooth dependence on initial conditions of 1st order ODEs?

Comment: Oh,, thank you.(I havent studied ODE theory)